# Xampp installed and running, cannot connect using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Just install xampp version 7 apache running on port 8000 MySQL running port 3306, phpmyadmin works, just created database, when I try run php website, just get "waiting for localhost" tried firefox too, same, nothing, any help please?

here is the opencart config.php less my connections

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost:8000');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'auctioneerslive');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Gary

Comment: Where do you define user and password? Where do you connect to the db?

Answer (score 2):

You messed up this line in the config
`define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost:8000');`
Your basically telling the script to connect to `localhost:8000:3306`. Remove the `:8000` part.

your config should look like this:

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'auctioneerslive');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Comment: I then get this 
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'gsc1ugs4949'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\auctioneerslive\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 7

Notice: Error: Could not make a database link (1045) Access denied for user 'gsc1ugs4949'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\auctioneerslive\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\auctioneerslive\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 58

Comment: i think it means that you have the wrong password for the user, did you also define `DB_PASSWORD` ?

Comment: Yes, I have basically exported db from online and reinstalled it in phpmyadmin

Comment: And have you recreated the username&password you were using online on your local machine? This is different from taking a mysql dump and import it in phpmyadmin

Comment: can I change in phpmyadmin to eliminate this? I did literally export to my local machine

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online on how to add a new user to a mysql. This is the first link i found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OE5WanVr9-8 . Search on how to add new users for your setup.

Comment: define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Radu Bogdan answer below

define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');